# What is the best way to prevent page reload using Jquery(ajax)?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Summary: I have a:

1) main page (Main.php)
2) simple .js script file (dashboard.js)
3) one other simple .php file (form1.php)
4) process.php, a file that processes the information sent by .js file (process.php)

Just like tumblr, I am trying to recreate the same "nav" experience - clicking the several options, replacing the main panel with the new code and when filling up the some form, send that info to BD and present the result in the Main.php

Everything is going well but the last step. After clicking the nav button (main.php), bringing the new form through javascript (dashboard.js + form1.php), filling up that form, I click the button and instead of not reloading the page (jquery->ajax), it sends me to the process.php file and presents me the result.

I have tried not to reload with "return false" and "event.preventdefault()" and still the same result.

JS Code

```
        $('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};

    that.find('name').each(function(index, value) {

        var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();

        data[name] = value;

    });


    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(html){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("ol#list-feed").append(html);
                    document.getElementById('set-width1').value='';
                    document.getElementById('tags').value='';

                }


    });
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `$('form.ajax').on('submit', function(event) {...});` and use only first preventDefault() and remove the return:false;

Answer (score 3):

You haven't defined `event`:

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the first line to:

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function(event) {
```

otherwise the `event` variable inside the function is undefined.

Comment: That's true even e.g chrome pass `event` implicitly. Not sure about all events and what's going on for other browsers

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //do other works here

}
```

or remove **event.preventDefault()** from everywhere and before  the end of this function just use **return false**.

Comment: I tried all the 4 suggestions/recommendations and unfortunately it doesn't work. I forgot to tell that in the last step, when calling the process.php, this one should return the processing of a function defined in other file (users.php). So, at the end of process.php there is the call to load_posts() and the result of it is what I should expect to appear in the main.php. Nevertheless, it shouldn't redirect me to process.php in the first place :\

Comment: try again with removing  preventDeafult() form ajax success method .

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
 $('form.ajax').on('submit', function(event) {
```